# How to avoid role escalation when using kube2iam

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

When attempting to setup a kube cluster on AWS we wanted to be able to associate IAM Roles with certain containers and therefore looked into using one of the many tools that will allow you to do this such as [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam).  All the tools seem to work the same way by proxying the assume role based on an annotation in the deployment.  Doesn't this allow for role escalation by allowing a container to assume a role from any other container by just changing the annotation?

From the kube2iam README:

> The problem is that in a multi-tenanted containers based world, multiple containers will be sharing the underlying nodes. Given containers will share the same underlying nodes, providing access to AWS resources via IAM roles would mean that one needs to create an IAM role which is a union of all IAM roles. This is not acceptable from a security perspective.

From my understanding the issue that is being described still exists if a malicious pod is introduced.  How are people currently solving this issue/is this something i should be worried about?

Comment: If you don't give the pods access to the Kubernetes API then how can they change their annotation?

Comment: @PixelElephant You're correct but im more concerned with the process of controlling the deployment pipeline and principle of least privilege is violated.  For example deploying 2 services to the same cluster "hello world" and "Personal information service" as someone with access to deployment of the "hello world" service to the cluster i should be unable to assume the role of the "Personal information service" but i can by just changing the annotation.

Comment: You're no longer talking about a malicious pod, but a malicious person. kube2iam can't help you with that. You could somehow build a system in your deployment pipeline that checks deployments for the existence of `iam.amazonaws.com/role` and validates it. But I know of no out of the box solution for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict the consumed roles by namespaces.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.amazonaws.com/allowed-roles: |
      ["role-arn"]
  name: default
```

With k8s RBAC enabled your deployment shouldn't have the permissions to update the namespace annotations.